# Find and Replace: find “all” but “preserve case sensitivity” when replacing

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, sublime-text-3

Does Sublime Text 3 or Notepad++ (two applications I commonly use) have the ability to find all instances regardless of case sensitivity but preserve the case when replacing?

For example:

- Find "stackexchanga" and replace with "stackexchange"
- This should find all instances but replace:

  - "Stackexchanga" with "Stackexchange"
  - "StackExchanga" with "StackExchange"

Or would that require some sort of regex?

Comment: In 2012 it was not the case in Notepad++: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8823794/4612235 . Maybe the perl-expression in one of the answers there is a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do two finds, first for the lower case version, and then for the upper case version?

I realise this might not work if you've got text with really WeiRd CasINg to the text.

Answer (score 0):

ST3 does this. Run `Find -> Replace...`, using the following values and options:

**Find What:** stackexchanga
**Replace With:** stackexchange
**Options:** Wrap (or not) and Preserve Case.

Hitting the `Replace All` button turned the following text:

```
Stackexchanga
StackExchanga
```

into:

```
Stackexchange
StackExchange
```

This is with the Mac version, build 3126.